# mysql multiple COUNT with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

i've designed a organization table as per below:

```
Name          Supervisor     Manager
David            -            -
Josseph         David         -
Jenny           Josseph      David 
Step            Josseph      David
Mike            Josseph      David
steven          David
```

The Chart above explain that, David is at the highest position of the organization, Josseph and steven are report to David; Jenny, step and mike reporting to Josseph.

I would like to know how many person are reporting to David; and David is the manager to how many person? This is my expected table:

```
Supervisor    Manager
2            3
```

Can it be done with only 1 query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f39ce/2

```
SELECT SUM(IF(Supervisor='David',1,0)),
  SUM(IF(manager='David',1,0))
FROM mytable
```

and here is an example of grouping query, if you ever need one:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdd738/5

```
SELECT t1.name,
  SUM(IF(t1.name=t2.Supervisor,1,0)),
  SUM(IF(t1.name=t2.manager,1,0))
FROM mytable t1
LEFT JOIN mytable t2
ON t1.name = t2.Supervisor
  OR t1.name = t2.manager
GROUP BY t1.name;
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, very simple, i like it! may i know what is the meaning of '1,0' inside that query ?

Comment: since we use `SUM` function in query we need to summarize something :-)  so when supervisor or manager equal to 'David' we increasesum +1 and when it is not equal we adding nothing +0

Answer (score 2):

It can:

```
select Name as BossName,
sum( case when Supervisor = Name then 1 else 0 end) as Supervises,
sum( case when Manager = Name then 1 else 0 end) as Manages
 from your_table group by Name;
```

This will get you something like:

```
BossName Supervises    Manages

David    2             3
Josseph  3             0
Jenny    0             0
....     0             0
```

Comment: don't want to downvote. but you query is not working at all. don't know who and why upvoted. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdd738/1

Answer (score 1):

Use the below query

```
select name,(select count(*) from <table> where supervisor=name) as supervisor,
(select count(*) from <table> where manager=name) as manager    
from <table>
```